# use normal browser profile as selenium profile

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

my os is Ubuntu 16.04, the default chrome profile is in :

`~/.config/google-chrome`

so i setup my selenium option with :

`options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome")`

but no luck, the error message :

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```